# user input - testing array for empty values *

Tags: php, arrays

```
check::empty_user()
```

below will test an array for 'empty' values -

> NULL, FALSE, 0, or ' '

```
/*check*/

class check 
  {
  static function empty_user($a)
    {
    return (int)!in_array('',$a); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php ?

Comment: Your version of `test_empty` doesn't even work properly; it only _ever_ analyses the first element of `$arg1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in_array('', $array);
```

I think that is what you're after?

Comment: That's a good idea.  However I think the OP wants the check to be recursive (if any of the elements of the array is itself an array then the nested array should be checked too).

Answer (score 2):

```
function test_empty(array $array) {
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        if (!empty($elem)) return false;
    }
    return true; // no element, or no non-empty element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't going to test anything other than the first element of your array.  Return causes the function to cease execution.

PHP has empty and isset functions, either of those should be suitable testing array elements.  To test the entire array you can use in_array and look for empty values.  However you'll have to implement your own method for processing nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You test empty could also be the folowing:

```
// if the array has at least one empty value
function test_empty(array $array) {
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        if (empty($elem)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary use

empty() or in_array()

and make note that:

$value=='' tests for null, false, 0, and ''